# KnockoutJS JQuery Combobox Binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'd like to make a binding for knockout which uses the [JQuery Autocomplete Combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) and allows for 2 way binding.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PPsRC/ from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537002/autocomplete-combobox-with-knockout-js-template-jquery) question has gotten a start, but doesn't fully implement the combobox functionality as on the jQuery demo site. (ie. selection highlighting, button styling, button not submitting the form, etc.).

Comment: There's no real question posed here. What are you having trouble with, specifically?

Comment: Since you haven't clarified what you're asking, I'm closing this as not a real question.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late, but I have a two way autocomplete combo box binding in my [Knockout UI](https://github.com/madcapnmckay/Knockout-UI) library (see Dropdown). Take a look and see if it helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have used http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ in my projects. It works perfectly over standard HTML control SELECT. So I have used standard bindings for managing SELECT (options, value, selectionOptions) and additional custom binding `chosen` to convert standard control to fancy one.

You could checkout usage example: http://jsfiddle.net/romanych/PcXrP/6/

There is code of binding. It is pretty simple

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function(elemenet, valueAccessor) {
        var chosenOptions = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(elemenet).chosen(chosenOptions);
    },
    update: function(elemenet, valueAccessor, allValuesAccessor) {
        // Subscribe to any change of underlying SELECT-element
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allValuesAccessor().value);
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allValuesAccessor().options);
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allValuesAccessor().selectedOptions);
        $(elemenet).trigger("liszt:updated");
    }
};
```

Comment: This binding is great, but how do you use it when you just want to bind to an array of text values without a name/value object?

Comment: Actually the same. `chosen` binding is just indicator that SELECT should be wrapped by `chosen` plugin. You should use regular `options` binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html without `optionsText` and `optionsValue` declarations

Comment: I had to replace the knockout reference in the fiddle with a different url to get it to work.  I used... http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.0/knockout-min.js