# AutoComplete in Jquery using knockout js

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, knockout.js

I am trying to do autocoplete using jquery.

I am using Editable Grid.[Like this](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html)

I tried to implement autocomplete the editable textbox present in the grid.
[My Code][http://jsfiddle.net/bhagirathip/x6H8s/4/]

Please figure out the what i did wrong .

when I trying to do autocomplete without Knock Out js queries it working fine but when i trying with the knock out js query it is not working .

Please figure out where i have done mistake.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a custom binding for autocomplete. Here is binding created by Ryan Niemeyer - [How to create an auto-complete combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537002/autocomplete-combobox-with-knockout-js-template-jquery).

Comment: I already tried this one.
This is not working for me.
Please suggest another one.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently from the code you have posted, you are actually trying to initialize autocomplete **before** the elements are created.

The applybinding will bind your data on iddle (after a timeout of 0 ms) which means after the $() has returned and more important after the `$('.txtMemberSearch').autocomplete({...})` has run.

I think you should try Artems proposal.