# Jquery autocomplete with knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete with knockoutjs. Its working fine with keyboard and mouseclick events. But my problem is that, when i type any name that not present, its showing that name in my page(stored in abservable variable).

Here is my javascript code:

```
 //For autocomplete extender generating members
$(function () {
    $('.tags').autocomplete({

        //make ajax call to get all mentored member of logged member
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Members.aspx/GetAllMembers",
                data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                    self.memberOptions(data.d);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('error occured while autocomplete');
                }
            });
        },
        minlength: 0,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //get selected member name
            self.selectedMember(ui.item.actualValue ? ui.item.actualValue : ui.item.value ? ui.item.value : "");
            self.LoadAddress(self.choosenDateId(), self.selectedMember());
        }
    });
});
```

My need is that, when i type an invalid name, the page should show address of loggeduser(present in session). i.e self.selectedMember(userName).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added below block after select event and it works:

```
change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                //if invalid name selected, load goals of logged user
                self.selectedMember(userName)
                self.LoadAddress(self.choosenDateId(), self.selectedMember());
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing native jQuery code with knockout, dont do it. The whole point with KO is to remove the dependency between model and view. Use a autocomplete binding instead

[How to create an auto-complete combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537002/autocomplete-combobox-with-knockout-js-template-jquery)