# Issue with jQuery autocomplete 1.9.2 and knockout

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, knockout.js

I've been using this knockout binding from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MJQ6g/) ([from this initial SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537002/autocomplete-combobox-with-knockout-js-template-jquery)) for a while and it has been working.

After upgrading to jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery UI 1.9.2 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexZeitler/SJZdA/)), when typing text into the input, after the items list is populated (but not selected!), the input textbox is cleared and you have to restart typing from the beginning. That's annoying as you won't be able to complete your text input because you always have to start from scratch.

If the `jqAutoSourceInputValue` and the `jqAutoSourceValue` have the same property name, it works, but then either the id or the input value after the selection are not the desired one.

Comment: There is also a native KO combobox, https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Combobox (And yes I'm the same Anders)

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue is coming from the fact that the binding's `update` function has a dependency on the observableArray that is being updated.  I am not quite sure what has changed in jQuery UI to make the actual behavior change from before, but one fix is to update to Knockout 2.2.1 and access the observableArray via the `peek` function to avoid a dependency.  Something like:

```
var source = (ko.isObservable(allBindings.jqAutoSource) ? allBindings.jqAutoSource.peek() : allBindings.jqAutoSource) || [];
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xXuq6/

If you can't update to KO 2.2.1, then there are some other ways to do it as well. Let me know.

Comment: Updating to 2.2.1 and your code fixed it. You made my day! Thanks.