# Change select drop-down option based on input value using autocomplete in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, autocomplete

Using Knockout JS, when a user types into an input field and selects a value (ex: Fruit) using jquery-ui autocomplete selection, I'm trying to change the select drop-down of options in a separate drop-down.

Example scenario: 
(1) User begins to type "Fru.."
(2) Selects "Fruit" in autocomplete input field.
(3) Dropdown options changes based on the value: "Fruit"
(4) Dropdown options only shows "Apples" or other options with equals id (ex: ABC)

Autocomplete Input Field

**HTML**

```
<input type="text"
    id="searchItem"
    placeholder="Search"
    tabindex="0"
    data-bind="textInput: searchItem, valueUpdate: 'onkeyup'"/>
```

**ViewModel/JQuery (Autocomplete)**

```
// Search Item
$(function() {
    var searchItem = [
        { id: "ABC", name: "Fruit" },
        { id: "DEF", name: "Animal" },
        { id: "GHI", name: "Color" },
        { id: "JKL", name: "Clothing" }
    ];

    $("#searchItem").autocomplete({
      source: searchItem
    });

 });
```

---

**Select dropdown**

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control"
        id="alphabetList"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        tabindex="0"
        data-bind=" foreach: { data: alphabetList, as: 'item' }, value: selectedItem">
    <option data-bind=" attr: { 'value': item.id }, text: item.name"></option>
</select>
```

**ViewModel**

```
// Alphabet List
this.alphabetList = ko.observableArray([
    { id: "ABC", name: "Apples" },
    { id: "DEF", name: "Dog" },
    { id: "GHI", name: "Green" },
    { id: "JKL", name: "Jacket" }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On selection of an item in `autocomplete`, populate an observable called `selectedId`. Then create a [`computed`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) property which filters the `alphabetList` based on `selectedId`

You have not mentioned where this `autocomplete` code exists. But, since you have mentioned `ViewModel`, I'm assuming you have access to the viewModel's instance in your jquery code.

Also, you don't need to use the `foreach` binding for displaying options. You can use [`options`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) binding.

Here's a working snippet with all these changes:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.selectedAlphabet = ko.observable();
  self.selectedId = ko.observable();
  self.searchItem = ko.observable();
  
  self.alphabetList = ko.observableArray([
      { id: "ABC", name: "Apples" },
      { id: "DEF", name: "Dog" },
      { id: "GHI", name: "Green" },
      { id: "JKL", name: "Jacket" }
   ]);

  // this gets triggerred everytime selectedId changes 
  self.availableAlphabetList = ko.pureComputed(() => {
    return self.alphabetList().filter(item => item.id == self.selectedId());
  });
}

// I have created an instance to use it in jquery code
var instance = new viewModel();

ko.applyBindings(instance);

$(function() {
   var searchItem = [
   { id: "ABC", name: "Fruit" },
   { id: "DEF", name: "Animal" },
   { id: "GHI", name: "Color" },
   { id: "JKL", name: "Clothing" }];

  $("#searchItem").autocomplete({
    // creating an array with a "label" property for autocomplete
    source: searchItem.map(function(item) {
      return {
        label: item.name,
        id: item.id
      }
    }),
    // on select populate the selectedId
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // if this jquery code is within viewModel, then use "self.selectedId"
      instance.selectedId(ui.item.id)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<input type="text" id="searchItem" placeholder="Search" tabindex="0" data-bind="textInput: searchItem, valueUpdate: 'onkeyup'" />

<select class="form-control" id="alphabetList" data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="0" data-bind="options: availableAlphabetList, 
                      optionsText: 'name',
                      optionsValue: 'id',
                      value: selectedAlphabet
                      optionsCaption: 'Choose..'">
</select>
```

You can also go through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537002/how-to-create-an-auto-complete-combobox/) which has good answers for creating a custom binding for autocomplete

Comment: This looks good. Unfortunately, I'm having difficulty running it using a Durandal JS framework. The ViewModel is asking me to define the "instance". trying to add JQuery to a viewModel

Comment: @EricCarr This is just an example. `instance` in this case in a new instance of the `viewModel`. As I wrote in comments, you'd have to change it to `self` or `this` if the autocomplete code is inside the `viewModel`.