# autocomplete and remove default value

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I want to do 2 things as soon as the input-box gets focus:

- autocomplete (default dropdown)
- remove the default-value as

  ```
  $(".keywordbox > input").autocomplete({"source":"/nl/video/show-keywords/3", "maxLength" : "10" });
  $(".keywordbox > input").focus(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == $(this).prop("defaultValue")) {
          $(this).val('');
      }
      $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
  });
  ```

The autocomplete on focus works fine, except when it is combined with

```
 $(this).val('');
```

Anyone suggestions to make this work?

** EDIT **

Seems that autocomplete does not work because the input is empty. Even when there is no placeholder-value set.

What I want is that de autocomplete sets of without giving a value, so that all options (without filtering) can be given.

Comment: Please add a fiddle.  You can use jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like

```
$(".keywordbox > input").focus(function() {
```

to

```
$(".keywordbox > input").keydown(function() {
```

but it is optinal and for your question try like

```
if ($(this).val() == $(this).prop("defaultValue")) {
    $(this).val('');
    return false;
}
```

and better than to put default value add placeholder like

```
<input placeholder="default value">
```

SIMPLY GIVE LIKE THIS

```
$(".keywordbox > input").focus(function() {        
    $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
});
```

Comment: This does not work. I've tried this.
It is because the input has an empty value.

Comment: I've found it: 

     $(".keywordbox > input").autocomplete({"source":"/nl/video/show-keywords/3", "maxLength" : "10", "minLength": "0" });


I found it on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268531/jquery-autocomplete-view-all-on-click

Answer (score 0):

The solutions is simple ... adding the following code

```
"minLength": "0"
```

Then it becomes

```
$(".keywordbox > input").autocomplete(
     {
     "source":"/nl/video/show-keywords/3", 
     "maxLength" : "10", 
     "minLength": "0" 
 });
```